# Can what-clauses modify directly their previous noun phrases?

Tags: modifiers

> (1) “You know **what** I think that sounded like?”
>   (2) I made it my mission to figure out **what** it was that had evoked such primal feelings in my wife and me that morning. 
>   (3) And perhaps that’s because of **what** they represent. 
>   (4) They could not rule out the idea *that* **what** I heard was a mountain lion. 
>   (All are from ‘[Monsters in the Woods](http://www.nytimes.com/2014/10/13/opinion/monsters-in-the-woods.html?ref=opinion)’, NYT)

In (1)~(3), *what*’s are fronted for adding complements to transitive verb, phrasal verb, preposition. But there is ‘*that*’ before ‘*what*,’ in (4). This noun phrase,‘*the idea*,’ may be in apposition with the ‘*what-clause.* Can ‘*that*’ be omitted in here? 
In other cases, can *what-clause* be a modifier that modifies its previous noun phrase, just on which heels, e.g. without ‘*that*’ etc.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***What I heard*** is a fused relative.  It's the subject of the subordinate clause ***what I heard was a mountain lion***, which is marked as subordinate by the subordinator ***that***:

> *that*<sub>subordinator</sub>　 **what I heard**<sub>subject</sub>　 was<sub>predicator</sub>　 a mountain lion<sub>predicative complement</sub>

We can paraphrase the whole thing like this:

> They could not rule out the idea [ *that* **the thing I heard** was a mountain lion ].

Or, paraphrased more loosely:

> They thought it was possible [ *that* **what I heard**  was a mountain lion ].

There is no noun phrase before ***what I heard*** in this example; we can see that it's not in apposition with anything.

Comment: Can this be an example of apposition? - (1) She had tried, over the years, to put him out of her mind, but it was hard to shut out the sensation of happiness, _what_ she'd briefly known with him. If it is, is this (2) the same case as (1)?: (2) They could not rule out the idea, _what_ I heard was a mountain lion.

Comment: I’d like to know if in (4) of OP, is ‘_that_’ a subordinator to modify previous noun phrase? If this phrase is separated by comma, don’t you need the suborninator, _that_?

Comment: @Listenever The difference between the examples in your comment is that in (1), "what she'd briefly known with him" is a noun phrase, while in (2) "what I heard was a mountain lion" is a clause.

Comment: Thank you. And though they are different: one is a phrase the other a clause, they are both in apposition with their former nouns, aren't they?

Comment: @Listenever Would you like to question separately this?